# How can i add leadin numbers to a list that is empty and i fill it with input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.6

so this is my code

```
list_of_idea = []

while True:
    ask = input("What is your new idea ? :")
    list_of_idea.append(ask)
    print(list_of_idea)
```

When I run it, it shows a list, for example:

```
[first idea , second idea , third idea, ...]
```

What can i do so when i run the program it will show :

```
1.first idea 
2.second idea 
3.third idea 
...
N. N idea.
```

And if I restart the program the ideas will still remain in the list

Comment: Can do that by printing the list in a for loop, and appending the index / counter before the value (i.e. just for printing sake).

Comment: what do you mean by append the index/counter before the value ?

Comment: Keep a counter and increment it everytime, and then use it in the print function

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo OP is not concerned about printing the values. Read the last line mentioned by OP *if I restart the program the ideas will still remain in the list*.

Comment: @Anwen you want to store `ideas` in `list_of_ideas` every time you run your program while retaining values from previous executions?

Comment: @Ch3steR yes for that storing of the list in a file can be done. (Answer by Filip 
 below)

Comment: i want to store them in the list. even if i restart the program and i want them to be counted

Comment: @Anwen you can use pickle for saving the list

Comment: pickle ? how can i save with a pickle ?

Comment: i can`t find the directory for the pickle, the one i created . how can i saved it ?

Answer (score 1):

The ideas cannot remain in the list beacuse a list is created during Runtime. If you want to write the ideas somewhere, probably the easiest way is to write it to a `*.txt` file.

```
with open("idea_list.txt", "a") as file:
    list_of_ideas = []
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        ask = input("What is your new idea?\n")
        list_of_ideas.append(ask)
        print(f"{count}) {ask}")
        file.write(f"{count}) {ask}\n")
```

After you run it once the file `idea_list.txt` should be created in the same directory the script was.

A better way to organize them would be to see what idea you were last on and then start counting from there this can be done by doing this:

```
with open("idea_list.txt", "r") as file:
  line = file.readline()
  while line:
      count = int(line[0])
      line = file.readline()
file.close()

with open("idea_list.txt", "a") as file:
    list_of_ideas = []
    while True:
        count += 1
        ask = input("What is your new idea?\n")
        list_of_ideas.append(ask)
        print(f"{count}) {ask}")
        file.write(f"{count}) {ask}\n")
```

Comment: Yes but the file should be created first. When you run the program once you should read from it and see what idea you where on from the last time you run your program.

Comment: I think it is better now :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the length of your list to determine the current index:

```
list_of_idea = []

while True:
    ask = input("What is your new idea ? :")
    list_of_idea.append(f'{len(list_of_idea) + 1}.{ask}')
    print(list_of_idea)
```

output:

```
['1.first idea', '2.second idea' ...]
```

if you want to persist the list even if you close the program than you have to use a file to save the list or a data base.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the list_of_idea in pickle format when you want to save it. After that you can load the pickle which contain the list of idea

```
import pickle
list_of_idea  = []

while True:
      ask = input("What is your new idea ? :")
      count = len(list_of_idea)
      list_of_idea.append( str(count+1) + '. ' +  ask)
      action = input("enter yes or no, for saving list")
      if action == 'yes':
         with open('idea.pkl', 'wb') as f:
              pickle.dump(list_of_idea, f)
         break
     else:
         pass
     print(list_of_idea)


#op
['1. how', '2. are', '3. you']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a separate method to print your ideas list in a chosen format. Something like the code below should work for you.

```
def print_ideas(ideas):
   for index, idea in enumerate(list_of_ideas):
      print("{}. {}".format(index+1, idea))
list_of_ideas = ['First idea', 'second idea', 'Third idea']
print_ideas(list_of_ideas)
```

Full solution should look like this:

```
def print_ideas(ideas):
   for index, idea in enumerate(list_of_ideas):
      print("{}. {}".format(index+1, idea))

list_of_idea = []
while True:
    ask = input("What is your new idea ? :")
    list_of_idea.append(ask)
    print_ideas(list_of_idea)
```

Answer (score 0):

This case will print every "1.idea". After asking.

```
list_of_idea = []

while True:
    ask = input("What is your new idea ? :")
    list_of_idea.append(ask)
    print("{}.{}".format(len(list_of_idea), ask))
```

> What is your new idea ? :asda
>
> 1.asda
>
> What is your new idea ? :asdadasd
>
> 2.asdadasd

The variables won't be saved after an execution, despite you don't save them on a file.